# ¿Es una buena practica crear relaciones de este modo?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Les dejo un ejemplo gráfico de lo que estoy implementando, y me gustaría saber si es una buena practica esto.

[image: Relaciones en MySQL]

Les explico. un cliente puede realizar muchos pagos, pero a su vez un socio también puede realizar pagos, entonces, ¿tendría que realizar una tabla de pagos para cada entidad (clientes, socios)?

Comment: debes crear en la tabla Pagos, un idCliente y un idSocio. De ese modo, dependiendo de cuál tengas informado, podrás saber si peretenece a un socio o un cliente. A partir de ahí, si los pagos tienen las mismas carácterísticas, no tendrás problema... (como lo tienes, vaya) . El problema que si mal no recuerdo, al tratarse de FKs, no tengo claro si podrás poner NULL en la tabla pagos en esos campos. En ese caso, puedes pasar de la relación FK y simplemente mantener la tabla de pagos sin mayor problema, permitiendo NULL en los campos de pagos, No es necesario tener FKs xa mantener la integridad..

Comment: Eso es correcto, como veras, de esa manera lo he planteado. La tabla pagos tendrá los mismos campos. En otras palabras mi solución podría ser ¿Establecer los campos foráneos como NULL?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta depende demasiado de opiniones: para mí estás usando una tabla como si fuesen dos: pagos_clientes y pagos_proveedores. Tener dos tablas con la mitad de datos ocupa casi lo mismo y las búsquedas pueden ser más rápidas

Comment: exacto... pero también ocupan más los índices y a la hora de mantenibilidad, duplicas también la funcionalidad. Bienvenido a los paradigmas del diseño!!! :)  La verdad que ahí debes ser tú el que decida eso, valorando si las tablas, por ejemplo, tendrán reglas de archivado diferente, o si los clientes o los proveedores, tienen números muy diferentes de pagos a realizar, o si por ejemplo, querrás realizar informes sobre uno de los grupos.. etc..

Comment: Las tablas `clientes` y `socios` seria mas conveniente que sean una sola tabla para evitar problemas con las FK y diferenciar los registros con un tipo ("cliente" o "socio")

Comment: No se trata de ese tema kevin, la pregunta se formula basada en como diseñar una database donde se puedan presentar ese tipo de casos.

Comment: Creo que hay otra confusion aca.. y esto esta basado en opiniones totalmente.. los pagos.. por mas que se llamen pagos.. sirven para lo mismo??? o sea.. asi pague un cliente o un socio son el mismo pago? pq en ese caso no tiene sentido tener dos tablas "clientes", si no una que se llame "clientes" y tenga un campo que indique si tambien es socio.. habria que tener mucho mas contexto. @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz porque ocupan mas los indices?? ocupan lo mismo, el overhead es despreciable...

Comment: En el modo "todo en una tabla", cada registro indexa 1 campo más... haz cuentas de la cantidad de NULL que tienes indexados.. afectando además al rendimiento...

Comment: Según tu diseño actual, cuando un cliente pague, la columna `socios_id` será una columna *vaga, ociosa*. Me podrás decir que es un `INT`, que no es para tanto. De todos modos, tienes ahí una columna *ociosa*. Y cuando un socio pague, lo mismo. O sea, que por cada registro en tu tabla vas a tener una columna haciendo nada. Como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, hace falta comprender el contexto. Hay pequeños detalles que podrían cambiar muchas cosas, por ej. ¿los clientes pueden ser socios?... Como quiera que sea, si fuera yo, nada más por esa columna *ociosa*, me plantearía otra solución.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz siempre y cuando uses ese campo como indice... y los null no se indexan...

Comment: pero cada registro es más grande, y SIempre lo vas a utilizar dada la situación!!! :)

Comment: en definitiva... para mi gusto mucho mejor utilizar 2 tablas.. pero... la lacra es la que hemos comentado, la mantenibilidad, duplicar métodos,  etc.. aunque ello tampoco tiene xq ser malo!! :P

Answer (score 2):

Más allá de si es buen diseño o no, sería mejor pregunta:

¿Este diseño cumple con el objetivo que estoy persiguiendo?

Voy a darte dos puntos de vista, los más habituales

### Diseño más Formal

**PROS**: La principal ventaja de normalizar el modelo son las reglas que explicitamente agregas al negocio, impidiendo que desde tu software se puedan producir incongruencias (posiblemente debido a fallos software). En definitiva, un modelo robusto.

**CONS**: Será más rígido, tendrás que tener en cuenta las restricciones del modelo cuando tengas que introducir cambios y también será más lento, debido al incremento de uniones que tendrás que realizar entre Entidades (Pagos, Clientes, Socios, etc.) y relaciones (Pago_Cliente, Pago_Socio, etc.)

Definir una relación en función de si el valor es NULL o no, no es muy buena práctica cuando lo que buscas es un modelo formal. En lugar de esto, define relaciones entre las entidades como esta:

[image: Normalizar el modelo...]

Otra ventaja sería que en hipotético caso de agregar otro tipo de "perfil" de pago, con crear otra relación ya lo tendrías... sin agregar otro campo a null ;)

[image: Otra relación más...]

### Diseño orientado al tiempo de respuesta (web)

**PROS**: El acceso a la información es directo. La información se recupera con facilidad y debes considerar que llamadas estás realizando y en función a que información recuperas en cada momento, determinar si vale la pena "desnormalizar" el modelo en pro de la velocidad (si es lo que quieres).

**CONS**: Al desnormalizar el modelo, la información comienza a duplicarse (sobre todo las claves) y la responsabilidad de la integridad referencial de la información recae sobre la capa software de datos/negocio. Es posible que bugs comprometan la información y/o

En este caso y suele ser el de muchas páginas web con un número de visitas elevado, te toca en ocasiones desnormalizar el modelo en función del tiempo de respuesta que quieras obtener. No se si será tu caso.

Tu ejemplo se acerca más a esa situación, acceso rápido a la información...

Aquí te tienes que hacer las siguientes preguntas:

1. ¿Tu aplicación accederá a la información al mismo tiempo?
2. ¿O tendrás una consulta para los pagos de los clientes y otra para los pagos de los socios?

En el primer caso, si consultas los pagos todos "juntos", tu modelo funcionará. En el segundo caso, si de verdad tienes muchos registros y tu consulta tarda mucho, deberás desnormalizar y quizás aplicar técnicas de **[SHARDING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture))** (el clásico divide y vencerás)

Por ejemplo, aplicando Sharding horizontal sobre tu tabla lo más evidente es dividir pagos de socios de pagos de clientes...

[image: Desnormalizado]

Espero que te ayude a decidirte en relación al objetivo que estas persiguiendo.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es mala, pero mezcla muy peligrosamente conceptos de diseño de base de datos relacional para ABM con datawarehouse, lo que la hace de por si bastante compleja y no solucionable. Nunca en un sistema de ABM se recomienda desnormalizar. Solo se desnormaliza en sistemas de concentracion y muestra de datos (warehouse) que pueden o no estar en la misma base de datos. Y en cuanto al diseño.. todavia no me quedo claro que es un pago...